# Calling delete on 'slice' is not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I got this error only in IE-11 otherwise my React app is working fine in all browsers.This error (Calling delete on 'slice' is not allowed in strict mode.) is coming in the developer console and my web app page went blank. I am using React 16.8.4 and  @babel/core 7.2.2. Below are my .babelrc file config

```
{
"presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "useBuiltIns": "entry", "corejs": 3}], "@babel/preset-react"],
"plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose":true } ]
]
```

}

Comment: What code is producing this error?

Comment: Likely just need some polyfill for IE11. [react-app-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill) is an excellent package for this.

Comment: Ok let me try this package

Comment: @VLAZ   `var myObject = {
    "newValue": "PRIVMSG",
    "oldValue": "OLD_VAL",
};
delete myObject.oldValue;`

Comment: Can you provide any sample which can help to produce the issue? It can help us to understand the issue in a better way.